# How do I show the battery percentage on a MacBook Pro by code? (AppleScript, do shell script, etc.)

Tags: macos, command-line, applescript, command-prompt

There is a button called Show Percentage when we click the battery icon, how do I enable the button using code? thx.

**Edit:**

So, I found a way to do this by UI control, but this is not ideal, anyone?

Go to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Accessibility, check Script Editor.app

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    try
        set bettaryIcon to first menu bar item of menu bar 1 whose description starts with "Battery"
        click bettaryIcon
        click (the first menu item of menu 1 of bettaryIcon whose name = "Show Percentage")
    end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information about the Power state from System Profiler via

```
do shell script "system_profiler SPPowerDataType
```

Then you need to extract the line containing the percentage information (I don't have a portable MAC so I can't test it) with `awk`

```
do shell script "system_profiler SPPowerDataType | awk '/Hibernate Mode/ {print $NF}'"
```

Replace `Hibernate Mode` with the text of the line containing the required information.

Answer (score -1):

pmset -g batt (terminal) has some info about battery.